# Use get_dummies to turn categorical values to numeric?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I am making a simple reproducible example to understand how training and testing works:

**Example**

I want to predict `Ages` based on `Location` of origin:

```
import pandas as pd

# create a simple dataset of people
data = {'Name': ["John", "Anna", "Peter", "Linda","John","John","John"],
        'Location' : ["Paris","Paris","Paris","Paris", "New York", "Berlin", "London"],
        'Age' : [24, 23, 21, 24,36,34,36]
       }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

At this part below, it has a problem with the city names, therefore I decided to use dummy variables but the line with the `get_dummies` is not correct. I think it needs to turn both `Name` and `Location` strings to dummy variables and that's what I tried but what is the proper way?

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X = df.drop('Age', axis=1)
y = df['Age']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.20)

from sklearn.svm import SVC
svclassifier = SVC(kernel='linear')
X_train = pd.get_dummies(df.columns)  #<---- here is the issue probably
svclassifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = svclassifier.predict(X_test)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not define your features (X) and target (y). Your X is where your model learn to predict your target y. Since your feature is **Name** and **Location** which is categorical then you need to use auto encoder like get_dummies.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
#features
X = pd.get_dummies(df[['Name','Location']])

#Target
y = df['Age']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.20)

from sklearn.svm import SVC

svclassifier = SVC(kernel='linear')
svclassifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = svclassifier.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: Can you show the appropriate way to evaluate the results because when I type y_pred I don't know what I am seeing

Comment: The resulting model y prediction are `print(y_pred) # [24 36]` which age 24 and 26, and the predicted X feature are `print(X_test.index) #[ 1 4]` which means John from Paris is 24 and John from NY is 36.

Comment: Yeah, I mean it says [36,24] but what row does each correspond to? Would it be helpful to show for example: the row that was actually john paris 24 was predicted as "predicted values" or something like that.

Comment: Please make that part about the results more clear in the answer cause I don't know what the results correspond to.

Comment: If the resulting prediction is [36, 24] , and if your X_test.index is [1, 4] then the model predicted it wrong, since X_test.index gives you the order of features to predict.

Comment: So I type y_pred. Then I type X_test.index.Then I go to the df and see the actual values of the ages for these indexes and check if they were predicted correctly?

Comment: Try `print(X_test.T)` and you will find the names and locations of your target prediction

Comment: Also evaluate your model. Try add this code `from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score` and `print('Accuracy: ' + str(int(accuracy_score(y_pred, y_test))))`. It will give you the accuracy score of your model prediction.

Comment: Thanks, by the way do you know if the `fit` should be `fit(X_train, y_train)` or `fit(X_train, X_test)` ? because here it says that as `y` parameter it takes the labels: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/statistical_inference/model_selection.html#score-and-cross-validated-scores

Comment: Always use `fit (X, y)` and it should be train for training and test for testing, because your model will learn how to predict y using X. So when your model `predict(X_test)` , it will give y based on what the model learned from `fit(X_train, y_train)`.

Comment: why isn't there a need for a `transform` or `fit_transform`?

Comment: Because your data is 0 to 1, you use transform to scale your data, try read this link: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/12321/difference-between-fit-and-fit-transform-in-scikit-learn-models#12346

Comment: I suggest, try this free course in Machine Learning Introduction, it helps me alot to learn about building model. https://www.kaggle.com/learn/intro-to-machine-learning

Answer (score 1):

`svclassifier.fit(X_train, y_train)` takes an array as input, but you feed a pandas DataFrame. Try using `sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder` istead of `pd.get_dummies`.

**Edit:** Example with `LabelEncoder` and `OneHotEncoder`:

```
# create a simple dataset of people
data = {'Name': ["John", "Anna", "Peter", "Linda","John","John","John"],
        'Location' : ["Paris","Paris","Paris","Paris", "New York", "Berlin", "London"],
        'Age' : [24, 23, 21, 24,36,34,36]
       }

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.svm import SVC
import numpy as np

X = data['Location']
y = data['Age']

# Label
print("Label Encoded")
le = LabelEncoder()
le.fit(X)
X_enc = le.transform(X)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_enc, y, test_size = 0.20, random_state=42)

svclassifier = SVC(kernel='linear')
svclassifier.fit(np.reshape(X_train,(X_train.shape[0],1)), y_train)
y_pred = svclassifier.predict(np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0],1)))
print(f"y_pred: {y_pred}, y_test: {y_test}")

# OneHot
print("OneHot Encoded")
ohe = OneHotEncoder()
ohe.fit(np.reshape(X,(len(X),1)))
X_oh = ohe.transform(np.reshape(X,(len(X),1)))

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_oh, y, test_size = 0.20, random_state=42)

svclassifier = SVC(kernel='linear')
svclassifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = svclassifier.predict(X_test)
print(f"y_pred: {y_pred}, y_test: {y_test}")
```

Gives:

```
Label Encoded
y_pred: [24 24], y_test: [24, 23]
OneHot Encoded
y_pred: [24 24], y_test: [24, 23]
```

Not too bad.

Comment: Please since this is a reproducible example, type your approach that you suggest to see what you mean and also why is this happening. thanks

Comment: isn't Label encoding biased due to the order of the number and one hot encoding is more preferable?

Comment: That could be the case. I added an onehot example to my original minimal example, but the results are identical.